# deadLock using multiprocessing.Pipe

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, process, multiprocessing, pipe

**I'm trying to create a process to communicate with a thread.**

I'm trying to send data to the process, and the process need to do something with the data, and return the answer.

I don't understand what is the problem.

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.name = "RemoteWorker_%s" % id(self)
        # Queue shared with all threads
        self.tasks = tasks
        # Pipe's shared with the current thread(self) and the process
        self.procInput, self.threadOutput = Pipe(duplex=True)
        self.threadInput, self.procOutput = Pipe(duplex=True)

        # Create Process for running the Tasks.
        self.proc = Process(target=execute,
                            args=(self.procOutput,
                                  self.procInput))
        self.proc.start()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            (func, args, kargs), _ = self.tasks.get()
            func(self, *args, **kargs) # parent_proc_runner

    def put(self, arg):
        self.threadOutput.send(arg)

    def get(self):
        return self.threadInput.recv()

    def stop(self):
        self.tasks.put((StopIteration, None, None))  # stop thread
        ProcessTask.KillProcess(self.proc.pid)  # kill process

def execute(q):
    procInput, procOutput = q
    rc = None
    exception = None

    while True:
        args, kwargs = procInput.recv()
        rc, exception = runner(*args, **kwargs)
        procOutput.send((rc, exception))

def parent_proc_runner(worker, *args, **kwargs):
    rc = None
    exception = None
    worker.put((args, kwargs))
    rc, exception = worker.get() # here i'm in a deadlock
    return rc, exception
```

The same code i did it with Queue, and it worked, but i had performance issues.
please if someone can help me, i will appreciate it.

Thanks.